# Databricks user mapping with groups

Tags: databricks

Can we map single user in multiple groups in databricks?

I have requirement to add single user in multiple business groups in databricks.

These users are created using azure ad. So need to map mail-id with multiple groups so based on that I can manage rls and cls.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can add the same user into multiple groups. Just follow [documentation](https://docs.databricks.com/administration-guide/users-groups/groups.html#add-users-service-principals-and-groups-to-an-existing-group-using-the-account-console) on adding users/service principals into groups. Or you can use corresponding REST API or Terraform (the [databricks_group_member](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/databricks/databricks/latest/docs/resources/group_member) resource).